# How to show this inequality with a couple restrictions?

Tags: inequality

Question: Show $k\geq r$.

With:
\begin{align*}r=\frac{\lambda-\mu+\sqrt{(\lambda-\mu)^2+4(k-\mu)}}{2}\end{align*}

We know that:

- $v,k,\lambda,\mu\geq 0$
- $\mu>0$
- $k>\lambda, \mu$
- $r>0>s+1$
- $\lambda-\mu\geq -2k/(v-1)$

Comment: Why are $s, v$ here?

Comment: @Jean does this help?

Comment: @NoteMyQuestion The result is still not true. If it was, you could let $\mu$ tend to $0$ and $\lambda$ tend to $k$ to see that it is impossible. I gave a numerical couterexample in my answer.

Comment: What we can say is that $r$ is the biggest of the two roots of the quadratic equation:
$x^2+(\mu-\lambda)x+(\mu-k)=0$
i.e., we have 
$r^2+(\mu-\lambda)r+(\mu-k)=0$, but after that, what is the need of the different constraints on variables $s,v$ that play no role...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe do you know if it still holds when all variables are integer? Can this just be scaled up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true.

Consider $\lambda=100$, $k=100.01$, and $\mu=0.01$.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B100-0.01%2B%5Csqrt%7B%28100-0.01%29%5E2%2B4%28100.01-0.01%29%7D%7D%7B2%7D

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut OP just changed their constraints. Literally seconds ago.

Comment: Sorry. Possibly forgot the most important one. We also know $k>\lambda, \mu$